# Qual a diferença entre Integrated Security e Persist Security?

Tags: sql-server, connectionstring

Nas strings de conexão com o SQL Server normalmente vejo as opções `Integrated Security` e `Persist Security`, O que significa cada uma delas e quais valores elas podem receber?

<sub>Essa dúvida me surgiu vendo os comentários da seguinte pergunta: [Erro "Login For User Failed" no serviço windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318977/88361)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Integrated Security** significa a forma de autenticação do banco:
- se "false", você deve informar login e senha na string de conexão;
- se "true", não são necessários login/senha, pois será utilizado o usuário autenticado no Windows.

**Persist Security** significa se a informação de login será salva ou não quando houver a conexão.
- se "false", a nível de código, uma vez feita a conexão, você pode obter as informações da string de conexão **menos** login/senha;
- se "true", as informações da string de conexão são retornadas **incluindo** login/senha;

Claro que se usar `Integrated Security=true`, `Persist Security=true` passa a ser irrelevante, uma vez que a informação de login/senha não vai estar presentes na string de conexão.

Mais detalhes aqui: [connection string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)